# How do I call a custom method from a button in a view to delete a file associated with an object? Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm working on a rails app where users can post links with title, url and an uploaded image file. When displaying this link I want to have a delete picture button next to the image so that the user may click on it to delete the image.

I don't know which is the best way to do this, but here's what I did:-

Custom method in links_controller.rb:-

```
  def destroy_picture
    @link = current_user.links.find_by(id: params[:id])
    if @link.picture? && @link.user==current_user
      new_link = @link.dup
      new_link.picture=nil
      new_link.id = @link.id
      new_link.created_at = @link.created_at
      new_link.updated_at = Time.now
      @link.destroy
      new_link.save
      flash[:success]="Picture deleted successfully"
    end
  end
```

Calling the custom method in the view:-

The complete files:-

link_controller.rb

```
class LinksController < ApplicationController
  before_action :logged_in_user, only: [:new, :create, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :link_owner, only: [:edit, :update, :destroy]

  def new
    @link = Link.new
  end

  def create
    @link = current_user.links.build(link_params)
    if @link.save
      flash[:success]= "Link submitted successfully"
      redirect_to root_path
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def edit
    @link = current_user.links.find_by(id: params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @link = current_user.links.find_by(id: params[:id])
    if @link.update_attributes(link_params)
      flash[:success] = "Link successfully edited"
      redirect_to current_user
    else
      flash[:danger] = "Link edit failed"
      render 'edit'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @link = current_user.links.find_by(id: params[:id])
    @link.destroy
    flash[:success] = "Link successfully deleted"
    redirect_to root_path
  end

  def destroy_picture
    @link = current_user.links.find_by(id: params[:id])
    if @link.picture? && @link.user==current_user
      new_link = @link.dup
      new_link.picture=nil
      new_link.id = @link.id
      new_link.created_at = @link.created_at
      new_link.updated_at = Time.now
      @link.destroy
      new_link.save
      flash[:success]="Picture deleted successfully"
    end
  end

  private

    def link_params
      params.require(:link).permit(:title, :url, :picture)
    end

    def link_owner
      link = Link.find(params[:id])
      user = link.user
      redirect_to current_user unless current_user == user
    end
end
```

_link.html.erb:-

```
<div class="container">
  <li class="row">
    <span class="avatar">
      <%= image_tag link.user.avatar_url(:thumb) if link.user.avatar? %>
    </span>
    <span class="content">
      <b><%= link.title %></b> -
      <a href=<%= link.url %>><%= link.url %></a>
    </span>
    <span class="image">
      <%= image_tag link.picture.url if link.picture? %>
    </span>
    <span class="content">
      <% if link.user==current_user %>
        <%= link_to "Delete Picture", link_path(link),
            method: :destroy_picture,
            class: 'btn btn-xs btn-danger' %>
      <% end %>
    </span>
    <span class="timestamp">
      Posted <%= time_ago_in_words(link.created_at) %>
      ago by <%= link_to link.user.name, user_path(link.user)%>
    </span>
    <span class="content">
      <% if current_user==link.user %>
        <%= link_to "Edit", edit_link_path(link),
            class: 'btn btn-xs btn-primary' %>
        <%= link_to "Delete", link_path(link),
            method: :delete,
            data: {:confirm => "Are you sure?"},
            class: 'btn btn-xs btn-danger' %>
      <% end %>
    </span>
  </li>
</div>
```

This link partial may appear either on the home page or the user's profile page.

Currently I am getting `param is missing or the value is empty: link` when I click on the "delete picture" button. How do I get around getting the method to be executed?

Also in general, what would be the simplest way of doing this?

Comment: Can you update the question with the server log generated when you click on the delete picture?

Comment: Also share your `routes.rb` code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace your `link_to` helper with the route which points to the method to destroy such picture, and in the method use the corresponding HTTP verb, that's `delete`:

```
<%= link_to "Delete Picture", destroy_picture_path(link), method: :delete, class: 'btn btn-xs btn-danger' %>
```

Be sure you're passing the `link` object, to receive it in your controller and find the object in the database.

Also your routes must point as a `delete` action to your method:

```
delete '/links/:id', to: 'links#destroy_picture', as: 'destroy_picture'
```

Comment: This worked. Thanks. But I'm wondering why it must be a 'delete' method. Is it because I'm calling @link.destroy in the method definition? Or can this be achieved by replacing 'delete' with 'patch' in both the routes and the link_to helper? To put it more simply, does the choice of method depend on what's within the definition in the controller action or can it be arbitrary?

Comment: Because in order to delete an specific resource you must the `delete` HTTP verb, by default `link_to` makes a `GET` request. Also because your routes must be specified as `delete`, so, they must match. Patch could be used to specify a modification to an specific resource. [This](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods) might help.